# Chi squared test - difference between 95% and 99% probability

Tags: probability, chi-squared

can anyone help me to understand using the critical values table to determine probability in a chi squared test in biology? If the chi sq value is 4 (for example) and the critical value for 0.05 is 3.8, we reject the null hypothesis. However, if the 0.01 probability value is 5, would we then have to accept the null hypothesis? This seems to be a contradiction: to 95% certainty that we should reject the null hypothesis, but a 99% certainty that we should accept the null hypothesis....

Thank you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We do not accept a null hypothesis.

We reject the null hypothesis at $95\%$ confidence level, but we do not have enough evidence to reject the null hypothesis at $99\%$ confidence level.

Note that accepting and do not reject are not the same.

Comment: Thank you, that is very helpful.